# How to get rid of Copy&Paste using Cell function In Excel VBA with double loop?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am optimizing a very old macros code and I noticed that it does useless action to copy data from Sheet "Source" to "Test" and afterwards - to the right destination sheet "Overview".

Is there any way to get rid of an extra sheet "Test" and Selection, CutCopyMode, et cetra?

```
Dim i As Integer
   Dim m, n As Integer
   Rmin = Application.InputBox("Min row.")
   Rmax = Application.InputBox("Max row.")

   For i = Rmin To Rmax
    For j = 1 To 99
      Sheets("Source").Select
      Cells(i, j).Select
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.Copy

      Sheets("Test").Select
      Cells(1, j).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste

    Next j
      Sheets("Test").Select
      Range("A1:PK1").Select
       Selection.Copy

      Sheets("Overview").Select
      Range("A2").Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste

     Range("A3:I54").Select
     Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\...." & File & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next i
        Sheets("Source").Select
        Cells(Rmax, 1).Select
```

Thank you!

Add. information: Macros is used to create a PDF of each user selected row in the Sheet "Source", afterwards data form selection at Sheet "Overview" is used to create PDF. And I am new to the whole VBA environment, however, I try my best. I am already using the Application.ScreenUpdating to reduce run time.

Comment: For working code in need of optimizations, [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place. For select replacement, look here: [How to avoid using Select in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear to me which cell gets copied where in the long run, but in general you can always avoid the .copy / .paste commands by using the syntax below:

```
  For i = Rmin To Rmax
    For j = 1 To 99
      Sheets("Overview").Cells(2,j).Value = Sheets("Source").Cells(i, j).Value

    Next j
```

In this case, you specify the value of the cell on the left to be equal to the content of the cell on the right.

Best regards
seulberg1

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried something like this but unsuccessfully. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you can easily skip the pasting to the test-sheet.
Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim m, n As Integer
Rmin = Application.InputBox("Min row.")
Rmax = Application.InputBox("Max row.")

For i = Rmin To Rmax
  Sheets("Source").Select    'Move to the source sheet
  Range("A" & i & ":PK" & i).Select  'Select the row to copy
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Selection.Copy     'Copy the row

  Sheets("Overview").Select  'Move to "Destination"-sheet
  Range("A2").Select   'Paste source into A2 (for some reason)
  ActiveSheet.Paste

  Range("A3:I54").Select  'Select the are you want to create a pdf of
  'And create the PDF...
  Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Users\...." & File & ".pdf" _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next i  'Move to next row in source sheet

Sheets("Source").Select   'Move back to source
Cells(Rmax, 1).Select     'Select the last cell.
```

Hope this helps speed things up :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It cut the run time time by 80%. :)